Lyapunov function of perturbed linear time-varying ODE system
I am considering an ODE system as follows:
$$\dot{x}(t) = A(t)x(t) + g(t,x),$$
where $A(t)\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ for any $t\geqslant t_0$, and $g(t,x)$ is a vanishing perturbing term (i.e., $g(t,0)=0$ for all $t\geqslant t_0$) satisfying $\Vert g(t,x)\Vert\leqslant \gamma \Vert x\Vert$ (edit: Here $\gamma \rightarrow 0$ when $\Vert x\Vert \rightarrow 0$ ). I want to find a Lyapunov function that meets two conditions: (1) $\alpha_1(\Vert x\Vert)\leqslant V(t,x)\leqslant \alpha_2(\Vert x\Vert)$; and (2) $\frac{d}{dt} V(t,x(t)) = \frac{\partial V}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\dot{x}(t)\leqslant -\alpha_3(\Vert x\Vert)$, where functions $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$ are class-$\mathcal{K}$ function. Choosing the Lyapunov function of its nominal system $\dot{x}(t) = A(t)x(t)$ ,$V = x^T P(t) x$ where $P(t)$ satisfies matrix differential equation $-\dot{P}(t) = P(t)A(t)+A^T(t)P(t)+Q(t)$, seems quite reasonable. Here $Q(t)$ can be any continuous positive-definite time-varying bounded matrix. We can assume $0<c_1I\leqslant Q(t)\leqslant c_2I$. The solution of above matrix differential equation is given by $P(t) = \int_{t}^{\infty} \Phi^T(\tau,t)Q(\tau)\Phi(\tau,t)d\tau$, where $\Phi(\tau,t)=e^{\int_{t}^{\tau} A(s)ds}$ is the state transition matrix of the nominal system.
My attempt: It is easy to verify that this Lyapunov function meets condition (2), by properly bounding the perturbing term when taking derivative of it. If assuming that the $0$ equilibrium point of nominal system is exponentially stable (implying that $\Vert \Phi(\tau,t)\Vert\leqslant ke^{-\lambda (\tau-t)}$), then the upper bound of $V$ can be obtained by $$V(t,x)\leqslant \Vert x\Vert^2 \cdot c_2\int_{t}^{\infty}\Vert \Phi(\tau,t)\Vert^2d\tau \leqslant c_3 \Vert x\Vert^2.$$
However, I just cannot bound the $V$ from below. I have already known how lower bound is obtained in the linear time-varying situation, by assuming that $\Vert A(t)\Vert \leqslant L$, and the state-transition property that $\Phi(\tau,t)x(t;t_0,x_0) = x(\tau; t,x(t))$. But it is not the same in the perturbed system. I have chosen the $\Phi(\tau,t)$ as the state transition matrix of the nominal system, and the solution of original system doesn't have state-transition property in terms of $\Phi(\tau,t)$.
My question: Is the $0$ equilibrium point of this perturbed system reach stability for sure? If not, is there counter-example? If so, can anyone bound the $V$ from below in the form of a class-$\mathcal{K}$ function? Any reasonable extra assumption is allowed to made, and any other form of Lyapunov function is welcomed.

What makes you believe that there exists a Lyapunov function for the perturbed system in the first place? I think $\Vert g(t,x)\Vert\leq \gamma\Vert x\Vert$ is not enough even if the nominal system is globally exponetially stable.

Yes I was commenting the same, it suffices to consider $g(t,x):=-A(t)x+I_n x$, it is a ``subinear perturbation term'' (satisfying the bound if $A(\cdot)$ is bounded), but the system is clearly unstable, even if the non-autonoumous system $\dot x(t)=A(t)x(t)$ is uniformly exponentially stable.

@SampleTime Yes, I don't believe every perturbed system should have a Lyapunov function. But I think it is reasonable to try some "most likely" functions to see if this particular kind of perturbed system exists a feasible one, particularly when the nominal system is simple enough to have a very nice Lyapunov function. And what if I restrict $\Vert g(t,x)\Vert$ to be leq than $\gamma \Vert x\Vert^2$? Do you think this stronger restriction makes the problem solvable?

@MatteoDR I've edited the post and add a constraint on $\gamma$. It is my fault to omit this important information. If $\gamma$ is an absolute constant, then the system is exactly not enough to reach stability. Thank you for your counter-example.

...I think that if the perturbation ``behave like'' $|x|^2$, then you can have local exponential stability: in a small neighborhood of the origin the non-linear perturbation is negligable with respect to the linear part, and the same Lyapunov function ''will work'' locally, in a small neighborhood. (Veeery roughly speaking).

Assume that $A(t)$ is such that the origin of the system $$\dot{x}(t)=A(t)x(t),\ x(t_0)=x_0$$ is globally uniformly exponentially stable. This is equivalent to saying that there exists a differentiable matrix-valued function $P(t)$ such that $$0\prec\alpha_1I\preceq P(t)\preceq\alpha_2I$$ and
$$
\dot{P}(t)+A(t)^TP(t)+P(t)A(t)\preceq -\alpha_3I
$$
for all $t\ge t_0$ and all $t_0\ge0$. An explicit solution for it is, for instance,
$$
P(t)=\int_t^\infty\Phi(s,t)^TQ(s)\Phi(s,t)ds
$$
where $\Phi(t,s)$ is the state-transition matrix defined as $x(t)=\Phi(t,s)x(s),t\ge s\ge t_0$ and satisfying $\Phi(t,t)=I$ for all $t\ge t_0$. The matrix-valued function $Q(t)$ is coercive and bounded.
Now consider the Lyapunov function $V(t,z)=z^TP(t)z$ for the perturbed system
$$
\dot{z}(t)=A(t)z(t)+g(t,z(t)),\ z(t_0)=z_0
$$
where $||g(t,z)||\le\gamma ||z||$ for all $t\ge0$.
Computing the derivative of $V$ along the trajedctory of the perturbed system yields
$$
\dfrac{d}{dt}V(t,z(t))=z(t)^T(\dot P(t)+A(t)^TP(t)+P(t)A(t))z(t)+2z(t)^TP(t)g(t,z(t)).
$$
We have
$$
2z(t)^TP(t)g(t,z(t))\le \epsilon z(t)^TP(t)z(t)+\epsilon^{-1}g(t,z(t))^TP(t)g(t,z(t))
$$
for all $\epsilon>0$. This implies that
$$
2z(t)^TP(t)g(t,z(t))\le \epsilon\alpha_2||z(t)||^2+\epsilon^{-1}\alpha_2\gamma^2||z(t)||^2.
$$
Therefore, we have
$$
\dfrac{d}{dt}V(t,z(t))\le (-\alpha_3+\epsilon\alpha_2+\epsilon^{-1}\alpha_2\gamma^2)||z(t)||^2.
$$
The value for $\epsilon$ that minimizes the right hand side is $\epsilon=\gamma$ which yields the upper-bound
$$
\dfrac{d}{dt}V(t,z(t))\le (-\alpha_3+2\alpha_2\gamma)||z(t)||^2.
$$
This implies that the origin of the perturbed system is globally uniformly exponentially stable if $$\gamma<\dfrac{\alpha_3}{2\alpha_2}.$$

Edit. For the lower bound for $P(t)$, just observe that there exists a sufficiently large $%c>0$ such that
$$
\dfrac{d}{ds}\Phi(s,t)^TQ(s)\Phi(s,t)\succeq -c \Phi(s,t)^TQ(s)\Phi(s,t).
$$
This follows from the boundedness of $\Phi(t,s)$ and $Q(t)$. Integrating both sides from $t$ to $\infty$ yields
$$
-Q(t)\succeq -c P(t)
$$
which yields
$$
P(t)\succeq Q(t)/c.
$$
The conclusion follows from the fact that $Q(t)$ is coercive.

Thank you for your kind answer! Your answer is sufficient to show that for small enough $\gamma$, the perturbed system is uniformly exponentially stable. I here want to further bound the Lyapunov function from below (if possible). There is no need to write in detail, and please let me know if you have any idea.

If you use the explicit $P(t)$ I gave, then we have that $V(t,x)=x^TP(t)x\ge c ||x||^2$ for some $c>0$.

But I still can't follow your first inequality after editing. Why is there necessarily exist such a large $c$? What if the trajectory of the nominal system has intense oscillation around the original point, while the norm of its trajectory is controlled by an exponential function? I don't think in this situation the derivative on LHS is lower bounded.

Can you find a $c>0$ such that $\dot Q(t)+A(t)^TQ(t)+Q(t)A(t)\succeq -cQ(t)$?

OK I now can get your idea. The middle of LHS of that inequality is just your comment's LHS. Now $Q(t)$ can be properly chosen that $\dot{Q}(t)$ is also uniformly bounded, then the proposed $c$ is reasonable. But I still don't think for any feasible $Q(t)$ in my post, the inequality of your comment has a solution...

Then you can use a density argument. Please try to spend a bit more time thinking in between your comments. I will stop replying to this thread from now on. Note also that $Q$ is a degree of freedom and you can pick the one you want in the stability condition, it does not matter much in the end.
